# Getting Input/Output error whenever trying to interact with LUN mounted through VMWare

Tags: rhel, disk, vmware

This is on RHEL 7.7, where I'm trying to mount a LUN through VMWare. The Disk shows up in `/dev` as `/dev/sdb/` but any interaction with it returns `Cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/Output error`.

Previous research points that this error means either the disk is

1. A improperly stopped NTFS disk
2. A broken disk

But neither of those are true, the disk has never been formatted as It was just made and I know for a fact that the disk isn't failing because many other things are also using LUNs on the same storage appliance without any issue.

Comment: Dos `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` get any errors? Does the system log show any more specific error messages `journalctl _KERNEL_SUBSYSTEM=scsi` ?

Comment: ``fdisk -l /dev/sdb`` gives the input output error. looking at journal ctl shows nothing relating to ``sdb``

Comment: It's odd that there's nothing in the logs about sdb. There should at least be a line that shows the mapping from sd Host:Channel:Target:LUN to sdb. I'm curious how the system decided which device sdb is.  If you do `cd /dev/disk/by-path;ls -l` do you see a symlink pointing to `../../sdb` and does its name look sensible?

Comment: Yes, its called ``pci-0000:03:00:00.0-scsi-0:0:1:0`` which is consistent with ``sda`` and ``sdb``

Comment: Hmm. Absent any error messages in the system logs, I'm not sure what the error could be. If I ran into this, I'd double-check all the configuration files on every component of the SAN, for example making sure there aren't any typos in the WWNs that would result in the host being denied access to the appliance's LUN.

Comment: There's not, and this seems to be a strictly RHEL related issue as it connects fine to other machines in my environment